# Need to optimize the query to insert the record

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I wrote a piece of JDBC template code, which inserts the record in the table, but the problem is my execution is stuck on this particular snippet, it seems some kind of hang up. I didn't figure out the cause as query properly running in sqldeveloper

```
List<SalaryDetailReport> reports = salaryDetailReportDAO.findAll(tableSuffix, regionId, circleId);
// the above line find the required data, if data is found then it proceeds

if (reports != null && reports.size() > 0) {
    for (SalaryDetailReport salaryDetail : reports) {
        try {
            SalaryDetail sd = new SalaryDetail();
            sd.setDetailReport(salaryDetail);
            salaryDetailDAO.save(sd, tableSuffix);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occured", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MyExceptionHandler(" Error :" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("data found");

} else {
    log.error("Salary Record Not Found.");
    throw new MyExceptionHandler("No record Found.");
}
```

You people saw try-catch , my execution stuck inside try and catch and here is the insertion code in my implementation class. when i commented the above code then my application works fine, but why my application stuck here, I am not able to figure it out, kindly help me

```
@Override
public void save(SalaryDetail details, String tableSuffix) {
    String tabName = "SALARY_DETAIL_" + tableSuffix;
//  String q = "INSERT INTO " + tabName + "(ID "
    String q = "INSERT INTO SALARY_DETAIL_TBL "
            + "                  (ID "
            + "                  ,EMP_NAME "
            + "                  ,EMP_CODE "
            + "                  ,NET_SALARY "
            + "                  ,YYYYMM "
            + "                  ,PAY_CODE "
            + "                  ,EMP_ID "
            + "                  ,PAY_CODE_DESC "
            + "                  ,REMARK "
            + "                  ,PAY_MODE ) "
            + "          (SELECT (sd.SALARY_REPORT_ID) ID "
            + "                  ,(sd.emp_name) emp_name "
            + "                  ,(sd.EMP_CODE) EMP_CODE "
            + "                  ,(sd.amount) NET_SALARY "
            + "                  ,(sd.YYYYMM) YYYYMM "
            + "                  ,(sd.pay_code) pay_code "
            + "                  ,(sd.emp_id) emp_id "
            + "                  ,(sd.PAY_CODE_DESC) PAY_CODE_DESC "
            + "                  ,(sd.REMARK) REMARK "
            + "                  ,(sd.PAY_MODE)PAY_MODE "
//          + "            FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_" + tableSuffix + " sd "
            + "            FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_TBL sd "
            + "            WHERE sd.PAY_CODE = 999 "
            + "            AND sd.EMP_ID IS NOT NULL "
//          + "            AND sd.EMP_ID NOT IN  (SELECT EMP_ID FROM SALARY_DETAIL_" + tableSuffix + ") "
            + "            AND sd.EMP_ID NOT IN  (SELECT EMP_ID FROM SALARY_DETAIL_TBL) "
            + "            ) ";

    MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    param.addValue("id", details.getId());
    param.addValue("EMP_NAME", details.getEmpName());
    param.addValue("EMP_CODE", details.getEmpCode());
    param.addValue("NET_SALARY", details.getNetSalary());
    param.addValue("GROSS_EARNING", details.getGrossEarning());
    param.addValue("GROSS_DEDUCTION", details.getGrossDeduction());
    param.addValue("YYYYMM", details.getYyyymm());
    param.addValue("EMP_ID", details.getEmployee() != null ? details.getEmployee().getEmpId() : null);
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(q, param);
//  details.setId(((BigDecimal) keyHolder.getKeys().get("ID")).longValue());
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to declare the parameters in the query? Like `WHERE ID = :id`? You should try your query in a database management tool, such as SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your query is Not In condition. It will degrade your performance. Try to fetch the "SELECT EMP_ID FROM SALARY_DETAIL_TB" in a separate query and pass in the Not in block in the main query. This will increase the performance of your query. Every time a save is performed this will fire the select query every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide whether you will insert records from `SELECT` or from the application.

---

If you don't need to manipulate with data after their select then you can simply call one `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement without any `for` cycle. It will be fast because of the only one `INSERT` statement call.

So you will implement method like `copyAllInSalaryDetail(tableSuffix, regionId, circleId)` in your `SalaryDetailReportDAO` and that method will execute `INSERT INTO salary_detail_tbl... (...) (SELECT ... WHERE ...)` using the same `WHERE` condition as you have in `findAll()` method. All inserts will be done only on the Database layer.

---

If you want to manipulate with data before their insert you can continue with your approach using `SalaryDetail` bean and `for` cycle, but you should remove the `SELECT` part from the `INSERT` statement and use values from the provided bean. Then the `save()` method can look like:

```
@Override
public void save(SalaryDetail details, String tableSuffix) {
    // use tableSuffix if it is really needed
    String q = "INSERT INTO SALARY_DETAIL_TBL "
            + "                  (ID "
            + "                  ,EMP_NAME "
            + "                  ,EMP_CODE "
            + "                  ,NET_SALARY "
            + "                  ,YYYYMM "
            + "                  ,PAY_CODE "
            + "                  ,EMP_ID "
            + "                  ,PAY_CODE_DESC "
            + "                  ,REMARK "
            + "                  ,PAY_MODE ) "
            + "          VALUES (:id "
            + "                  ,:emp_name "
            + "                  ,:emp_code "
            + "                  ,:net_salary "
            + "                  ,:yyyymm "
            + "                  ,:pay_code "
            + "                  ,:emp_id "
            + "                  ,:pay_code_desc "
            + "                  ,:remark "
            + "                  ,:pay_mode)";

    MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
//    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
//  details.setId(((BigDecimal) keyHolder.getKeys().get("ID")).longValue());
    param.addValue("id", details.getId());
    param.addValue("emp_name", details.getEmpName());
    param.addValue("emp_code", details.getEmpCode());
    param.addValue("net_salary", details.getNetSalary());
    param.addValue("pay_code", details.getPayCode());
    param.addValue("pay_code_desc", details.getPayCodeDesc());
    param.addValue("pay_mode", details.getPayMode());
    param.addValue("remark", details.getPayRemark());
    param.addValue("yyyymm", details.getYyyymm());
    param.addValue("emp_id", details.getEmployee() != null ? details.getEmployee().getEmpId() : null);
    getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(q, param);
}
```